# Why does my regex only change my first entry in SAS?

Tags: regex, sas

I have a number of text entries (municipalities) from which I need to remove the s at the end.

```
Data test;
input city $;
datalines;
arjepogs
askers
Londons
;
run;

data cities;
set test;
if prxmatch("/^(.*?)s$/",city) 
then city=prxchange("s/^(.*?)s$/$1/",-1,city);
run;
```

Strangely enough, my s's are only removed from my first entry.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You defined CITY as length $8.  The s in Londons is in the 7th position of the string. Not the LAST position of the string. Use the TRIM() function to remove the trailing spaces from the value of the variable.

```
data have;
  input city $20.;
datalines;
arjepogs
Kent
askers
Londons
;

data want;
  set have;
  length new_city $20 ;
  new_city=prxchange("s/^(.*?)s$/$1/",-1,trim(city));
run;
```

Result

```
Obs    city        new_city

 1     arjepogs    arjepog
 2     Kent        Kent
 3     askers      asker
 4     Londons     London
```

You could also just change the REGEX to account for the trailing spaces.

```
new_city=prxchange("s/^(.*?)s\ *$/$1/",-1,city);
```

Comment: In my actual data set i had made sure to STRIP the variable in question beforehand. This solution worked since stripping the variables doesn't seem to be enough, but I actually have to strip/trim them "inside" of the actual prxchange-function ^^

Comment: STRIP() removes both LEADING spaces and TRAILING spaces.  The LEADING spaces do not cause any trouble for your REGEX.  Note that SAS only has two types of variables, fixed length character strings and floating point numbers. So once you assign the result of STRIP() back to an actual variable the trailing spaces will be added back to fill out the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another solution using only SAS string functions and no regex. Note that in this case there is no need to trim the variable:

```
data cities;
  set test;
  if substr(city,length(city)) eq "s" then
     city=substr(city,1,length(city)-1);
run;
```